# Retrofit 2.0 handle error in json response

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm working on Retrofit 2.0 (which is awesome) to handle API responses.
All works well when API answers with success, I return the converted object wished from the json response

Here an example of request:

```
ServiceAPI.getUser(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
       User user = response.body(); // user is my POJO
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, final Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage())
    }
});
```

When response is done, I return the POJO (which is my main purpose), not the json to parse in order to avoid boilerplate.

So here my code to handle this :

```
// the interface to handle calls
protected interface ServiceAPI {
    @GET("/user/{userId}")
    Call<User> getUser(@Path("userId") String userId);
}

// the GSON part for converting data
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ItemTypeAdapterFactory())
    .setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'")
    .create();

// an interceptor to log requests responses
OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new LogJsonInterceptor())
    .build();

// the retrofit builder
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
    .client(okClient)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build();

// the interceptor to log requests
public static class LogJsonInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        String rawJson = response.body().string();
        Log.d(TAG, rawJson);
        // Re-create the response before returning it because body can be read only once
        return response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), rawJson)).build();
    }
}

// here the magic to handle json response and get data from "data" json key
public static class ItemTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

        final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {

            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            private RestError error;

            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

                JsonElement jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(in);
                if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    if (jsonObject.has("data")) {
                        jsonElement = jsonObject.get("data");
                    }
                }

                return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
            }
        }.nullSafe();
    }
}

// here the method to call from an activity for example to get an User
public static void getUser(final String userId, final Callback<User> callback) {
    serviceAPI.getUser(userId).enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            callback.onResponse(call, response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            callback.onFailure(call, t);
        }
    });
}

// here the call from the Activity
ServiceAPI.getUser(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
       User user = response.body();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, final Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + t.getMessage())
    }
});

// when API answers with success (code 200 from headers)
{
"data":
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"myname",
        "email":"myemail"
    }
}
```

So all works well here because I get response from "data" and convert the response into my POJO

**PROBLEM:**
But when API answers with an error (also with code 200 from headers), I get this:

```
{
"error":
    {
        "code":200
        "type":"OAuth_exception",
        "message":"You need an access token to get an user",
    }
}
```

The problem is that the retrofit "response" is nevertheless successfull and the errorBody is null

So here, I would to convert this into a RestError POJO (below) and send it inside the call when calling getUser method

```
public class RestError {
    private int code;
    private String message;
    private String type;

    public RestError(int code, String message, String type) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Any idea to fix that?

**UPDATE:**

I added this in the ItemTypeAdatperFactory

```
public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

                    JsonElement jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(in);
                    if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                        if (jsonObject.has("data")) {
                            jsonElement = jsonObject.get("data");
                        } else if (jsonObject.has("error")) {
                            jsonElement = jsonObject.get("error");

                            TypeAdapter<RestError> restErrorTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(RestError.class);
                            RestError error = restErrorTypeAdapter.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
                            return (T) error;
                        }
                    }

                    return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
                }
```

And I created a custom Callback like this:

```
public abstract static class CustomCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    public abstract void onError(RestError error);
    public abstract void onSuccess(T body);

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        if(response.body() instanceof RestError) {
            onError((RestError) response.body());
        } else {
            onSuccess(response.body());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
    }
}
```

So now how the call is:

```
ServiceAPI.getUser(new ServiceAPI.CustomCallback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onError(RestError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, error.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(User body) {
            Log.d(TAG, body.toString());  
            User user = body;  
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
```

So now when an error occurs I get it from onError(), otherwise onSuccess() and seems to do the job

What do you think about?

Comment: I actually had the same Problem,I was able to get the Response if it is 200.But what i want is to get the Stuff from 202.So for 200 Response we already created a SuccessResponse GSON class.And for 202 class also i have created another class depends on the JSON Response.

I couldn't manage to make use of both at a time.I tried like Extending also.But none of them works.Any Suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend all your POJOs from some `Response` class, which will contain field `RestError error`. Then you can make some `isSuccessful` method, which will check is `error` field `null` or not and handle it properly.

Comment: I think that's not correct for Retrofit 2.0. If the HTTP status code is not 200, then the responseBody is null and your POJO will be null, so extending is useless in this case.

Comment: @Geralt_Encore ,I tried  that ,it didn't fixed my  Problem

Answer (score 0):

In my view, you can customize your `ItemTypeAdapterFactory` like that to check if the reponse is your **data** or it is an **error**

```
public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
     JsonElement jsonElement = elementAdapter.read(in);
         if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
             JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
             if (jsonObject.has("data")) {
                 jsonElement = jsonObject.get("data");
             } else if(jsonObject.has("error"){
                 jsonElement = jsonObject.get("error");
             }
         }
    //TODO: need to handle your parsing here (to data or to error)
    return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
}
```

Comment: Yep! In the meantime I handled that in this way:
TypeAdapter<RestError> restErrorTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(RestError.class);
                            RestError error = restErrorTypeAdapter.fromJsonTree(jsonElement); 

But I still don't have any idea how to send this error instead of my User POJO

Comment: My way is:
`class YourResponse{
@JsonProperty("data")
 public ArrayList<User> data;
@JsonProperty("error")
 public ArrayList<ErrorResponse> error;
}`

`Call<YourResponse> getUser(@Path("userId") String userId);`

if you data != null, then it is not an error response. 
I used Jackon, not Gson, but the idea is something like it

Comment: I updated my question, what do you think about it? (thanks for your help guys)

Comment: So what do you think about this solution guys?

Comment: Can you send me your code to my email at thuongle.it@gmail.com. I will check it in my IDE. Maybe I can give you a solution for it